# AgglomerativeClustering big dataset

Tags: python, scikit-learn, bigdata, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I have a large dataset data_arr -  26 million rows.
I cluster it into 50 clusters
The best method that works for me for clustering is WARD.
With this method I have the most suitable results.

Using the following code to Clustering:

```
n_clusters = 50
connectivity = grid_to_graph(*data_arr.shape, n_y = 1)

ward = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters, affinity='euclidean', linkage='ward', connectivity=connectivity).fit(data_arr.reshape(-1, 1))
```

And it works well with datasets up to 3-4 million rows; if larger, it works indefinitely.

In principle, I understand why, but is there a way to somehow speed up this or is there a Ward method for clustering somewhere else? Maybe it’s possible to iterate not all the vertices, not every one of the 26 million?